# Find any of the arrays in postgres column

Tags: postgresql

Assuming I have a table with a column of type array, in my case double precision[].

I can't figure out how to find all the rows containing any of a list of arrays.

Example:

Let my column look like so:

[image]

What's the syntax for selecting the row containing, for example, {1,88} or {1,58}?

I tried a lot of variations of:

```
SELECT * FROM "table" WHERE "col1" = ANY('{1,88}, {1,58}');
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IN`.

```
...
col1 IN ('{1, 88}'::double precision[],
         '{1, 58}'::double precision[])
...
```

Comment: that works thanks. Why do I have to specify the type? Is it needed or just makes the code more clear or more efficient?